# beautifulsoup for subreddits

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, reddit

I have been trying to learn some html parsing with BeautifulSoup and tried to get it work for reddit. Here is my code,

```
!/usr/bin/python

import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BSoup
import os, re, sys, math, os.path, urllib, string, random, time

url = urllib.urlopen(sys.argv[1]).read()
    soup= BSoup(url)

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a',attrs={'class':'comments may-blank'}):
    links.append(link.get("href"))

print links
```

I have tested the code successfully for r/gaming and r/worldnews  but the code fails for r/gifs. I have also verified that the same class is used for all the subreddits. Plus I have tried with just

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
```

but still the code fails to find the hyperlink. Any suggestion on why this happens and how to make the code work with all subreddits.

Comment: Can you provide an example url?

Comment: Don't scrap Reddit. Use their API. As you're using python, I also suggest looking at [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.16/)

Comment: I would also recommend upgrading to  use bs4

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this too often you will be met with this.

```
As a reminder to developers, we recommend that clients make no
more than <a href="http://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API">one
request every two seconds</a> to avoid seeing this message.
```

Reddit does this to prevent abuse by spiders and crawlers.

Either space your requests OR much much more preferably use their Python api [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.16/) :